# how to understand the meaning and the intention of code in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

Can any one explain exactly what's the function of the code lies after `function exports()`, and why should i do it that way?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function Card() {
        this.isFaceUp = false;
        this.isUnplayalbe = false;
    }

    Card.prototype = {
        contents: function (v) {
            if (v === undefined) {
                return this._contents;
            } else {
                return this._contents = v;
            }
        },

        match: function (otherCards) {
            var score = 0;

            if (Array.isArray(otherCards)) {
                otherCards.forEach(compare, this);
            } else {
                compare.call(this, otherCards);
            }

            function compare(card) {
                if (card.contents() === this.contents()) {
                    score = 1;
                }
            }
            return score;
        }
    };

    function exports() {
        return new Card();
    }
    exports.Card = Card;
    window.card = exports;
})();
```

Comment: If you want to understand only a particular piece of code, please include only the relevant code in the question.

Comment: You cab read about exports helper here : http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html

Comment: A bit of context is always handy - but I would add a comment to the code or something so we can easily identify exactly what chunk of code you mean...

Comment: @shadow he means `exports.Card = Card; window.card = exports;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds Card property to window  object,  so  that this property will be a Function object   (meant executable)  because that Card property have assigned value of type Function  (export declared as function and assigned to Card)  but also that  Function object itself  will have  property  Card  which is Card  object and that executable property also can return new Card object  if  called....

- `window.Card`  is exports function
- `exports` function return new `Card` object  every time it called, so `window.Card` will do it too (`var card1 = window.Card()`)
- `exports` function have property `Card` (i don't know why it needed)
- so `window.Card.Card` - is a `Card` object too